# How to throw an error if not the record owner tries to modify

Tags: custom-button, validation-rule

I have a requirement that if the current user is not the record owner , he should not be able to modify the record. I have tried many ways. but its not working as expected. Anyone here please help me out !!!

Also i have a custom button which changes the lead owner to the current user logged in. So if the user who is not the record owner clicks on the button , the lead owner will be changed to his name.

My validation rule has to be like , if the current user who is not the record owner who tries to modify will have to be notified by the error saying that "U cannot modify the record unless you are the lead owner". On the other hand if he clicks on the custom button , the owner will be changed

Comment: Can you share what you did so far?

Comment: I have created a validation rule : 
AND( OwnerId <>  $User.Id ,  TECH_IsCurrentUser__c = FALSE)

.. On clicking "pick up" custom button , i make the checkbox true. But i am having another button called "put back" which makes the lead owner to a queue..

Comment: What is not working as expected

Comment: Please edit your post to show us the code for your validation rules, including the precise names for the fields you're using for your checkbox, etc. It's impossible to give you guidance without the proper information. It's not clear whether `TECH_IsCurrentUser` is the field name for the checkbox you're using to change the OwnerId. Somehow, I suspect that it's not.

Comment: @TusharSharma - I believe the Validation rule is conflicting with the button changing the owner

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are going about this the wrong way:

1. Set the leads OWD to public read only then?

Seems to be that would be preferred over trying to implement a solution that notifies the user after they make all their updates...

2. You can have your button call code that changes the user and that will happen in system context (without sharing) so it will run in lieu of the sharing rule